# Excel VBA Pivot Table data source issue

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-2013, vba

I have the following code...

```
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "page!R2C1:R1981C43", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="", TableName:="PivotTable5", DefaultVersion _
    :=xlPivotTableVersion15
```

How would i change it from "page" to pull for any current worksheet name that I want to attempt.

For example if I run this on a worksheet named "pages" it gives me an error, how would I change it to accept any worksheet name?

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare a variable and use that:

```
Dim myWorksheet as Worksheet
Set myWorksheet = Activesheet

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    myWorksheet & "!R2C1:R1981C43", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="", TableName:="PivotTable5", DefaultVersion _
    :=xlPivotTableVersion15
```

This is untested, but I'm pretty sure that should work.

Comment: It would be sheets.activesheets correct so it pulls from the currently active sheet?

Comment: @Rukgo - I updated the code, to use the activesheet, just do `Set myWorksheet = Activesheet`

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim wbpage as worksheet

set wbpage = thisworkbook.sheets(1) 'or whatever

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    wbpage.name & "!R2C1:R1981C43", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="", TableName:="PivotTable5", DefaultVersion _
    :=xlPivotTableVersion15
```